# Reading a file line by line, ignoring empty lines and some strings before EOF

Tags: java

I would like to read variations of the following file that will have to end with end but there may be empty lines after the final end or in some cases a special string "other".  There should only be one matching end for each of the below lines. If there's more than one "end" just stop, the only time there can be two "end" is just before EOF like below; abc has its matching "end" just before the EOF.

file1.txt
    **abc**
    def1
    end

```
def_2
end

def-3
end
end
```

**end**

other

the code I have so far but doesn't cater for empty lines or ignore the extra return for "abc"

```
String pl = null;
ln = r.readLine();
while (l != null ) {
   l = l.trim();
   if( !l.equals("") { //ignores blank lines
       if (l.equals("end")) {
           if (l.equals(pl) ) {
               endf = true;
           }
       }
       pl = l;

    }
    if (endf){
        System.out.println("found more than one end after the def");
        break;
    }
    l = r.readLine();
}
```

any one spot what i maybe doing wrong ??

Comment: Keyword `return` can't be identifier. Try to resolve Compiler error.

Comment: is ln supposed to be l ? or is there another l that you wont tell us about ?

Comment: Add a variable to keep track of the *def* you are in, then clear it when you find a *return*. If *def* can be nested, then you need a stack data structure instead of single variable.

Comment: once i find an extra "end" after the def. then i will break from the loop. only time i can have an extra "end" is before the EOF that end is the end for the matching abc.